# html pop up form always returns the first value

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

This is a C# MVC code wherein after searching the records from the database I am trying to display the records in each row *(which is working)*. Each row consists of `Update School` button along with other details including the `ChdId`. After clicking this button my View should return `schId` *(after selecting the school from the drop-down)* and `ChdId` corresponding to that row. But after submitting the `Update School` of any row I am getting the `ChdId` of the first row always in my Controller *(not of the row that I am updating)*.

**Question**:

Has anyone ever run into this issue before? Or does anyone know why this is happening, or what I'm doing wrong?

Please check out my code below and thanks for checking my question!

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateSchool(int SchoolNames, int ChdId, Child model)
{

}
```

**View**:

```
@model Ass4Final.Models.Child

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    var listOfSchoolNamesAndIds = ViewBag.SchoolNameAndId;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/JS/Search.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <br /> <br />
           <div>
               <table class="table" id="myTable" style="width:100%">
                   <tr>
                       <th>
                           @Html.Label("Child ID")
                       </th>
                       <th>
                           @Html.Label("Child Name")
                       </th>
                       <th>
                           @Html.Label("DOB")
                       </th>
                       <th>
                           @Html.Label("School Name")
                       </th>
                       <th></th>
                   </tr>

                   @foreach (var item in Model.DataChdNamCurrSchDOBProp)
                   {
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               @item.ChdId
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @item.ChdName
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @item.DOB
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @item.School
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                                   <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Update School</a>

                                   <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
                                       @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateSchool", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                                       {
                                           <h3>Enter New School</h3>
                                           @Html.DropDownList("SchoolNames", new SelectList(ViewBag.SchoolNameAndId, "schId", "schName"), "Select New School", new { @id = "MySearch" })
                                           <input type="hidden" value="@item.ChdId" name="ChdId" />
                                           <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="UpdateSchool">
                                       }
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   }

               </table>
           </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you expecting `ChdId` in your `action method argument` (or) `model`?

Comment: Seems that you're creating `BeginForm` and `DropDownList` inside a `foreach` loop. Multiple DDL with `name="SchoolNames"` may resulting only first record being submitted, you should use `for` loop and put the form tag outside the loop.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am expecting the correct ChdId in the action method argument. I am getting it in the action method argument, but it's always for the row 1.

Comment: @Tetsuya, my form structure is like that. I am using this link for creating pop up for each row [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_popup). On Clicking the pop up form and selecting the School, I need to click the Update School button.

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html, and your code that opens the popup will only ever the first popup, not the one associated with the row you are selecting

Comment: But what you should be doing is having only one for (generating all that extra html is degrading performance), and then using javascript to set the value of the hidden input when its displayed